# Вызов модального контроллера на Storyboard [iOS 7]

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, ios7

Привет всем пользователям ХэшКода! У меня опять вопрос по iOS разработке, подскажите пожалуйста как вызвать модальный контроллер по нажатию на кнопку, а потом его убрать. Вызвать у меня получается (перетянул от кнопки до контроллера и выбрал "Modal"). Всё вроде бы открывается, а вот спрятать никак не могу, помогите, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
```

Эту функцию нужно вызвать в методе модального контроллера, например, при нажатии на кнопку Назад, или какой-другой метод, который должен вернуть пользователя на предыдущий экран.

Comment: Не могли бы вы дать более развернутый ответ?

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, всё заработало :)

Comment: @AlexDenisov что требует дополнительного разъяснения? Я постараюсь ответить

Comment: @zhenyab, изначально в ответе был только кусок кода, который не является нормальным ответом.

Comment: Этот кусок кода закрывает модальный контроллер.

Comment: @Ковальский, я в курсе, кэп. С такими вопросами, как правило, приходят новички, и было неплохо давать более развернутый и вежливый ответ.

Comment: @AlexDenisov, В этом вопросе я полностью согласен с Вами :)

Answer (score 0):

Переходы можно осуществлять и без "паутин". Для этого создайте кнопку и в реализации пропишите:

```
UIStoryboard* storyBoard =  [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    view2ViewController *destViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view2"];

    [self presentViewController:destViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Где view2ViewController - контроллер, к которому вы хотите перейти
@"view2" - Storyboard ID Контроллера

Для перехода назад вам необходимо создать кнопку и прописать небольшой кусок кода, например так:

```
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```